# Inheritance: Schema not updated properly - some columns are missing in the table

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.7

There are three classes:

- class A is abstract and a `MappedSuperClass`
- class B inherits from A
- class C inherits from B

PHP-wise this works fine. Also generating `getter` and `setter` using `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities App` works.

#### The Problem

The problem comes when creasting the schema using `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`. Tables for class B and C are created. All columns from the abstract class are available, also the specialised fields from the classes B and C.

**Only the column `createdBy` is not generated in table C.** It's missing. It is created for table B though. Where's the problem?

#### Abstract Class A

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class A {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Blameable(on="create")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle[…]")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $createdBy;
}
```

#### Class B

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="b")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class B extends A {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $b;
}
```

#### Class C

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="c")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class C extends B {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $c;
}
```

**Note: I cleared chaches, using:**

```
app/console cache:clear
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

Comment: try removing the doctrine cache metadata launching the symfony shell command `php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`

Comment: @Matteo Thanks for your feedback. I cleared all caches multiple times. I've added this to the question.

Comment: Not an answer, but I seem to recall some discussion here on SO before about the general flakiness of multiple levels of inheritance with when using table inheritance... A question, from your description above I assume you are doing class table inheritance (as opposed to single table inheritance). If so don't you have to specify a `@ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")` ?

Comment: @Darragh Thanks for your reply. If I use `@ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")` then it will create a "base" table and "sub" tables with only the new/updated attributes. This would involve 1 or multiple joins and a discriminator column. I thought I could work around that and create tables that "stand on their own feet". I don't know how to phrase that better. Hope, you get me. ;)

Comment: Hi, so it sounds like you want to use single-table inheritance, but your setup doesn't seem to suggest that is what you are doing either. If you look at the [STI](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) docs (that's an unfortunate acronym!) you'll see that the inheriting table(s) don't specify a `@ORM\Table()` annotation. All that being said, I could have sworn I saw someone here experience all sorts of issues once they went further than one level of inheritance.